# Geometric interpretation of differential results

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I had a question which reads as follows.
A triangle has two of its angular points at $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$, and the third point $(x,y)$ is movable along $y=x$. If $A$ is an area of the triangle; show that $2(\frac{dA}{dx})=a+b$

While showing the result is no big deal, how do i think about this proposition geometrically? Or rather how do i approach the geometric aspect of these types of 'rates of changes' in general

Comment: $A$ is **an** area or **the** area of the triangle? If 'the', then assume $b > a$, therefore $A(x) = (b-a)x$ and $\frac{dA}{dx} = b-a$. I'm kinda confused there...

Comment: I believe its 'The' but i used the wordings of the question. I think its safe to assume it'd be The

Comment: The original version of the question says 'the', so I'll go with that. Then we would have $2(\frac{dA}{dx}) = b-a$, instead of $ = b+a$.

Comment: If a = b @ChristopherMarley, then the area would be static.

Comment: Assume $a\ne b.$The length of the base of the triangle is $|a-b|.$ The height of $(x,y)=(x,x)$  from the base-line $\Bbb R\times \{0\}$ is $|y|=|x|$ So $A=|x|\cdot |a-b|/2.$ If $x>0$ then $dA/dx=|a-b|/2.$

Comment: THE area. I never saw  a triangle with more than one area.

Comment: The area is variable, the third point moves along the line x=y. And 2(dA/dx)=a+b is a true fact which can be proven; i need insight on the geometrical aspect of this